# ActiveStorage Caching Setting - Rails + Google Cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, rails-activestorage

I am trying to set caching for the images stored in Active Storage with google cloud. I have the below configuration file

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

production:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("cert/gcs-production.json") %>
  project: 'my-app-121212'
  bucket: 'my-prod-bucket'

staging:
  service: GCS
  credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("cert/gcs-staging.json") %>
  project: 'my-app-121212'
  bucket: 'my-stage-bucket'
```

Can any one please suggests as to where i can specify the caching settings, I want the images to be cached.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `public: true` on the service. This will instruct rails to use public url from GCS which by default will have caching header added. Please refer to [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access)

Make sure your GCS bucket has public permission added (`allUsers` with viewer role)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using App Engine Flexible and not Compute Engine, caching files that are publicly readable object is allowed by default when using Google Cloud Storage, indicated by the  **service: GCS** flag you’re using, meaning that you do not have to specify any special configuration.

Keep in mind that the objects you can cache need to be static files, so images, stylesheets, JavaScript, etc.

If you wanna read more on serving static files from App Engine with Rails, you can read this [article from Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/serving-static-files#serving_files_from).